# Custom Launcher does not work

Tags: java, android

Iwanted to make a custom Android Launcher App, I needed some starting point for that thing searched for it, I have got some code for custom Launcher App from [github.com/AxelMarchand/Purity](https://github.com/AxelMarchand/Purity/tree/4a34ad2f66102a9dbf535a82b228283c816130f7)

I have main class

```
public class Purity extends Activity {
    FragmentManager app_fragment_manager;
    PackageManager app_package_manager;

    ActionBarDrawerToggle app_action_bar_drawer_toggle;
    FrameLayout app_frame_layout;
    DrawerLayout app_drawer_layout;
    ListView app_list;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super .onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.app_layout);

        this.app_fragment_manager = getFragmentManager();
        this.app_fragment_manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.app_frame_layout, new PurityFragment()).commit();

        this.app_package_manager = getPackageManager();

        this.app_frame_layout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.app_frame_layout);
        this.app_drawer_layout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.app_drawer_layout);
        this.app_list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.app_list);

        this.app_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View parent, int position, long id) {
                ApplicationInfo app = (ApplicationInfo) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
                app_drawer_layout.closeDrawers();
                startActivity(app_package_manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName));
            }
        });

        this.app_list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View parent, int position, long id) {
                ApplicationInfo app = (ApplicationInfo) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + app.packageName));
                app_drawer_layout.closeDrawers();
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });

        this.app_action_bar_drawer_toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, this.app_drawer_layout, android.R.color.transparent, R.string.app_empty_string, R.string.app_empty_string) {
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                float moveFactor = app_list.getWidth() * slideOffset;
                app_frame_layout.setTranslationX(moveFactor);
            }
        };
        this.app_drawer_layout.setDrawerListener(this.app_action_bar_drawer_toggle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super .onStart();

        List<ApplicationInfo> apps = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();

        List<ApplicationInfo> apps_not_sort = this.app_package_manager.getInstalledApplications(0);
        for(ApplicationInfo app : apps_not_sort) {
            if(this.app_package_manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName) != null) {
                apps.add(app);
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(apps, new Comparator<ApplicationInfo>() {
            private Collator collator = Collator.getInstance();

            @Override
            public int compare(ApplicationInfo app0, ApplicationInfo app1) {
                return collator.compare(app0.loadLabel(app_package_manager), app1.loadLabel(app_package_manager));
            }
        });

        this.app_list.setAdapter(new PurityAdapter(this, R.layout.app_row, apps));
    }
}
```

and PurityAdapter is

```
public class PurityAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo> {
    public PurityAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ApplicationInfo> apps) {
        super(context, resource, apps);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v;
        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_row, parent, false);
        }else {
            v = convertView;
        }

        ApplicationInfo app = getItem(position);
        BitmapDrawable app_logo_src = (BitmapDrawable) app.loadIcon(getContext().getPackageManager());

        int app_icon_bitmap_drawable_size = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 32, getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        BitmapDrawable app_logo_rsz = new BitmapDrawable(getContext().getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(app_logo_src.getBitmap(), app_icon_bitmap_drawable_size, app_icon_bitmap_drawable_size, false));

        TextView app_label = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.app_row_label);
        app_label.setText(app.loadLabel(getContext().getPackageManager()));

        ImageView app_logo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.app_row_logo);
        app_logo.setImageDrawable(app_logo_rsz);

        return v;
    }
}
```

and PurityFragment.class

```
public class PurityFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_main_fragment, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super .onResume();
        final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getActivity());
        this.getView().setBackground(wallpaperManager.getDrawable());
    }
}
```

app_main_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/app_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textSize="48sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:text="@string/app_unlock"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

app_layout.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/app_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/app_list"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#333"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Manifest is

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@android:color/transparent"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/app_theme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Purity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/app_theme"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

all code works good without errors/exceptions but the thing is when I get only the screen as 
[image]

when I swipe that it does not swipe how and where can I make changes to make the app work?

Comment: So you posted all the code from a GPL project (make sure you honor the license when you write "your" custom launcher). And it's not working. Now you want us to trouble-shoot. This is exactly were your crazy coding skills come into play -- it won't be spoon fed.

Comment: If I have not provided he code you guys might have said __Please Post code__!!

Comment: No reason to yell. Now go to work.